# Objective-C UINavigationController odd behavior

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

I have an old obj-c project that has a UITabBarController with several UINavigationControllers as the tabs. All the navs seem to work fine, except one which breaks only in iOS11. This one, when I `pushViewControllerAnimated` the `viewDidAppear` of the pushed view controller never gets called. In addition, trying `popViewControllerAnimated` produces nil, although I can confirm the controller has a nav controller and that it is the top view in the stack. Has anyone hit this before? It's only in iOS11.

Answer (score 0):

The push to the nav controller was occurring in an async thread. If any UI actions are taken not on the main thread, there can be unforeseen consequences. Dispatching to main thread solved the problem.